# unlink(..): No such file or directory in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, unlink

I am using codeigniter3. now I want to delete records as well as related images but records deleted but it doesn't delete the images from the folder. every record has 3 images.

```
public function delete_by_id_and_img($id) {
  $image_file_name = $this->db->select('material_image')->get_where('tbl_raw_material', array('id' => $id))->row()->material_image;
        $cwd = getcwd(); // save the current working directory
        $image_file_path = $cwd."\\public\img\\";
        chdir($image_file_path);
        unlink($image_file_name);
        chdir($cwd); // Restore the previous working directory
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('tbl_raw_material');
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: you have to provide full directory path to inlink either with FCPATH OR base_url()

Comment: just check: `if(unlink($image_file_name)) { ...$this->db->delete('tbl_raw_material');... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$image_file_path='/project/folder/file_to_delete';
unlink($image_file_path);
```

You have to give full path of the file.

Comment: Not sure `localhost` is valid directory, it uses the os filesystem and not the network

Comment: @DanielKrom It was added only for the understanding. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but is your syntax with two \ in your path before public and after img correct?

```
    $image_file_path = $cwd."\\public\img\\";
```

Also check if / this will work for you , since \ I think, is for linux

Comment: I think there is a problem dueto couple of files like
unline(file1,file2,file3)
and i am not sure unlink delete multiple file or not.

Comment: have you checked $image_file_name in print_r() to see what you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Remove file from the folder - denied access of file so change the user and then unlink file

```
chown($path, 666); //Insert an Invalid UserId to set to Nobody Owern; 
unlink($path);
```